# Convert Scala foreach to .map

Tags: scala, syntax, dictionary, foreach, seq

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to convert code of the form

```
val series: ListBuffer[Seq[Seq[Any]]] = ListBuffer[Seq[Seq[Any]]]()
points.foreach(point => {
    if( conditionA )
        series += doA(...)  // returns a ListBuffer[Seq[Any]]
    else
        series += doB(...)  // returns a ListBuffer[Seq[Any]]
})
```

to use .map(). I'm thinking its something like:

```
val series: ListBuffer[Seq[Seq[Any]]] = points.map(point => {
    case conditionA => doA(...)
    case _ => doB(...)
})
```

but this doesn't compile because (I believe) the mapped sequences get appended as a single Seq[Any] instead of Seq[Seq[Any]], so I get the error

```
Expression of type Seq[Any] doesn't conform to expected type ListBuffer[Seq[Seq[Any]]]
```

Any ideas? Is there something wrong with syntax?

Comment: are doA and doB side-effecting?

Comment: no, they just modify the point in such a way to return a specific type of Seq

Answer (score 3):

Let me suppose a few things, you have some function `def doA(arg1: A): ListBuffer[Seq[Any]]` such that you ultimately want to arrive at a `List[Seq[Any]]` as the final result type after mapping this function over your collection. Then what you want is `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
 val series = points flatMap{ 
   case point if conditionA(point) => doA(point) result ()
   case point => doB(point) result ()
 }
```

The reason I make such a supposition is that the only reason you'd ever want to use a `ListBuffer[A]` in the general form is to create a `List[A]` through some side-effecting expression. Hence, you ultimately want a `List[Seq[A]]` as your final output.